# Model from URL/API/JSON CakePHP

Tags: php, rest, cakephp, cakephp-model

I have a new CakePHP install and I have a series of Web Service Endpoints in JSON, is it possible to populate a Model from this JSON in CakePHP?

They won't be connecting to a DB as all data comes from and submits to the web service.

I have no code as I cannot find any documentation on the CakePHP Models Site.

Answer (score 4):

### Rest datasource

The storage mechanism that a model uses is a datasource. By default Cake assumes a model will be used with a database but it can be anything that extends the `Datasource` class. There's [an example](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/datasources.html#an-example) in the documentation of a simple REST api datasource, and there are many more datasources in [the community datasources repository](https://github.com/cakephp/datasources/tree/2.3).

It's not necessary to build your own REST datasource though, there are existing solutions out there such as [this one](https://github.com/nodesagency/CakePHP-Rest-Datasource) which make using a model with a REST api rather trivial.

Examples from the readme:

```
User::find('all')               == GET    http://api.example.com/users.json
User::read(null, $id)           == GET    http://api.example.com/users/$id.json
User::save()                    == POST   http://api.example.com/users.json
User::save(array('id' => $id))  == PUT    http://api.example.com/users/$id.json
User::delete($id)               == DELETE http://api.example.com/users/$id.json
```

Comment: Seeing as none of the links works anymore and we are now at CakePHP 4, would you perhaps consider updating your answer?

Comment: anyone can propose an edit to all SO content :). I do not myself have new information here, but the general principle of creating a datasource to handle the relevant api operations still applies.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I really want to learn how to do this, but the documentation is no longer available. I really have no idea how to create REST as a datasource.

Answer (score 0):

I asked the same question and was told to look into this:  https://github.com/UseMuffin/Webservice

"Bringing the power of the CakePHP ORM to your favourite webservices."

I have yet to try it, but it seems like exactly like what we want.